# How can I get data of a child row in Jquery DataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatable

Currently when I get all the data associated with the data-table, the parent row data can be retrieved. But the child row associated with each parent row cannot be retrieved. Please advise.
Below is the approach that I'm currrenlty using.

```
 var rowIndex = table.row.add(newRow).index();
 table.draw();
 var row = table.row(rowIndex);

 var childRow =
                     '<tr>' +
                         '<td>' + ProcurementTypeRemarks + '</td>' +
                         '<td>' + EngineeringEstimateForeignRemarks + '</td>' +
                         '<td>' + EngineeringEstimateLocalRemarks + '</td>' +  '<td>' + '</td>' +
                 '</tr>';
 table.row(row).child(childRow).show().draw();
var gridData = table.data();
```

Comment: provide complete code and markup please

Comment: What do you mean by Child and Parent rows ?

Comment: i have updated the question. thanks.

Comment: Do you refer below row by saying child? And parent for above?

Comment: At the moment i'm using, var gridData = table.data(); which dosen't give the child data.

Comment: I attach html data- attribute to child row td, then retrieve attached value by jquery .data()

Comment: @TheCoon - Look at the answer given below. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it, if anyone comes across this issue, hope this would help.

```
var childRowRawHtml = jQuery.parseHTML(gridData.row(index).child()[0].innerHTML);
        var array = [];
        for (index = 0; index < childRowRawHtml.length - 1; index++) {
            var childJson = new Object();
            childJson = childRowRawHtml[index];
            var childControl = jQuery.parseHTML(childJson.innerHTML);
            var objct = {};
            objct[childControl[0].id] = childControl[0].value;
            array.push(objct);
        }
```